# JavaScript: how to dynamically add a Flash file (SWF) to the DOM so IE will load it

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, dom

I have pages that need to dynamically load content based upon their data description in XML files.  Among the items that may be dynamically loaded are SWFs.  I have code that correctly loads and starts the movies in Firefox via the http and file protocols and Chrome via the http protocol.  I need it to successfully load in Internet Explorer in both http and file protocols as well, but all Flash Video Player reports is 'Movie not loaded...'.  Could someone please review the following information and give me a fix?

The description of Flash objects in the XML looks like this:

```
<multimedia
    type='flash'
    swf='swf/filename_here.swf'
    width='600'
    height='400'
    version='7.0.19.0'
/>
```

I have JavaScript that parses this and creates an object that looks like the following JSON:

```
{
    'tag': 'multimedia',
    'attributes': [
        'type': 'flash',
        'swf': 'swf/filename_here.swf',
        'width': '600',
        'height': '400',
        'version': '7.0.19.0'
    ]
}
```

Eventually, this object is passed to a function that creates the DOM element (yes, I know the function is ordered oddly; I was trying different things to make it work):

```
var path = var path = document.location.href;
path = path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

var version = null;

function isIE() {
    return navigator.userAgent.lastIndexOf('Trident') > 0;
}

function buildFlash(element) {
    version = element.attributes.version;

    var name = document.createElement('param');
    name.setAttribute('name', 'movie');
    name.setAttribute('value', path + element.attributes.swf);

    (if (!isIE()) {
        var inner = document.createElement('object');
        inner.setAttribute('type', 'application/x-shockwave-flash');
        inner.setAttribute('data', path + element.attributes.swf);
        inner.setAttribute('width', element.attributes.width);
        inner.setAttribute('height', element.attributes.height);
    }

    var flash = document.createElement('object');
    flash.setAttribute('id', 'flashMovie');
    flash.setAttribute('classid', 'clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000');
    flash.setAttribute('width', element.attributes.width);
    flash.setAttribute('height', element.attributes.height);
    flash.appendChild(name);
    if (!isIE()) {
        flash.appendChild('inner');
    }

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id', 'multimedia');
    div.appendChild('flash');
    return div;
 }
```

The resulting div is eventually added to the correct location in the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: just use SWFObject to embed your swf's - http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ - it's been tested thoroughly and is cross-browser. Muuuuuch less work than the roll-your-own direction you have going.

Comment: I've looked into SWFObject.  I have not managed to convince anybody here at work that the MIT license SWFObject uses does not reuqire that we release our project under the MJIT license as well.  Nevertheless, I've tried the static implementation (since it was the easiest to excise SWFObject if I got a definitive 'no'), and it did not work.  I'm hesitant to try investing more time trying the dynamic approach, since that only works with SWFObject.

Comment: You should be fine using SWFObject as a library, if you keep it separate from your own code and include the copyright notice from the project page.

Comment: Sounds like a political battle, but the same thing would apply then to Adobe's embed classes. They're entirely wrong, but can you say that to them?

Answer (score 9):

IE does not support dynamically adjusting most of the attributes/parameters of the object element.

You can use this function to create a cross-browser object element with the given attributes and parameters.

```
var createSwfObject = function(src, attributes, parameters) {
  var i, html, div, obj, attr = attributes || {}, param = parameters || {};
  attr.type = 'application/x-shockwave-flash';
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    attr.classid = 'clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000';
    param.movie = src;
  }
  else {
    attr.data = src;
  }
  html = '<object';
  for (i in attr) {
    html += ' ' + i + '="' + attr[i] + '"';
  }
  html += '>';
  for (i in param) {
    html += '<param name="' + i + '" value="' + param[i] + '" />';
  }
  html += '</object>';
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = html;
  obj = div.firstChild;
  div.removeChild(obj);
  return obj;
};
```

Example

```
var swfEl = createSwfObject('http://example.com/example.swf', {id: 'myid', 'class': 'myclass', width: 100, height: 100}, {wmode: 'transparent'});
document.body.appendChild(swfEl);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is simple and seems to work. FYI, if (window.ActiveXObject) no longer return true in IE11, but that is ok because IE11 (and probably 10) supports flash embedding using the standard method (without classid and param.movie) anyway.

Comment: This also fixed my problem in FireFox and Edge.  And Chrome still works.  Thanks!