# Flash file not working when javascript function calling

Tags: javascript, html, flash

am new in flash

here am using  a javascript function for views a flash video

the flash files name are  a0.swf,a1.swf ...

this is my javascript function

```
<script>
var count=0;
function mafunct(newSrc){
    alert("hi");
var path="a"+count+".swf";  

 flash+='<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" CODEBASE="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%">';          
    flash+='<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="'+path+'">';          
    flash+='<PARAM NAME="PLAY" VALUE="false">';  
    flash+='<PARAM NAME="LOOP" VALUE="false">';
    flash+='<PARAM NAME="QUALITY" VALUE="high">';
    flash+='<PARAM NAME="SCALE" VALUE="SHOWALL">';
    flash+='<EMBED NAME="testmovie" SRC="Menu.swf" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%"PLAY="false" LOOP="false" QUALITY="high" SCALE="SHOWALL"swLiveConnect="true"PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/flashplayer/">';
    flash+='</EMBED>';
    flash+='</OBJECT>';     

count++;
alert(path+"aa");
}
</script>

<button onclick="mafunct()">next</button>
```

when this button click nothing will happen

Is here any problem with coding...

if you have the same isuue happened before and solve it or you know the answer for this please mention below

with regards ..Prasanth AR

**Update** my Question here..

```
<script>
var count=0;
function mafunct(flash){
var path="a"+count+".swf";  

    flash+='<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" CODEBASE="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%">';          
    alert(path);
    flash+='<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE='+path+' >';          
    flash+='<PARAM NAME="PLAY" VALUE="false">';  
    flash+='<PARAM NAME="LOOP" VALUE="false">';
    flash+='<PARAM NAME="QUALITY" VALUE="high">';
    flash+='<PARAM NAME="SCALE" VALUE="SHOWALL">';
    flash+='<EMBED NAME="testmovie" SRC="Menu.swf" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%"PLAY="false" LOOP="false" QUALITY="high" SCALE="SHOWALL"swLiveConnect="true"PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/flashplayer/">';
    flash+='</EMBED>';
    flash+='</OBJECT>';     
    alert(flash);
count++;

}
</script>

<button onclick="mafunct()">next</button>
```

and here the alerts are work but the flash id not viewed...

Comment: Is it just a typo in your question that you try to add to `flash` before declaring it? Line 3 of `mafunct`

Comment: sorry i don't get it...

Comment: In the line below `var path="a"+count+".swf"` you have `flash += '<OBJECT CLASSID...'`, before the variable `flash` exists. In the next line, `var flash = ...` is when you actually declare `flash`. And since you're assigning it to the same string in those two lines, do you actually need the line `flash += '<OBJECT CLASSID...'`?

Comment: ok..i got it and i edit the question but no change and u check it if i done correctly as you said

Comment: Are you getting the alerts? Or is the video just not showing?

Comment: video not showing and the hi alert only get

Comment: You want to keep the line that started with `var flash = <OBJECT CLASSID...`, not the one that started `flash += <OBJECT CLASSID...`

Comment: ok the 2nd time i edit it....

Comment: use value="file://"+path

Comment: you mean  flash+='<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="file://"+path">';

Comment: Yes. and also in the SRC="file://Menu.swf" as well..

Comment: the flash files are not in file it's in webcontent  i don't know is that a problem...

Comment: Do you still have the first line as `flash+='<OBJECT CLASSID=...`, or as `var flash='<OBJECT CLASSID=...`? I just tested it with the second one and I get both alerts. As for not getting the video to play, I'm guessing it might have to do with the fact that you're not adding the flash object to the page. As the code is now, you're just making a string and doing nothing with it.

Comment: first line as var flash='<OBJECT CLASSID=... and i got the 2 alerts but the flash file not working...

Comment: then i change it into flash+=''.... and got 1st alert only...

Comment: @jonhopkins you are right... but i don't know  how to adding the flash object to the page.it's not contain the question?...

Comment: I found something that might be helpful for adding the object to the page... http://stackoverflow.com/q/5070432/1053938

Comment: @jonhopkins adding the flash object to the page  it's not contain my question?..

Comment: I added an answer. Let me know if it helps. I have to go take an exam so I'll be back later.

Comment: @jonhopkins thanx for your help... but your answer is right but i am looking for change the flash file only when click the button if you free now please check my code in question and if there is code for   flash object to the page.

Comment: @jonhopkins i just update the question but the flash is not working there...

Comment: @Anna.P pls help with this prblm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using what I found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5070432/1053938), I think this should help.

```
var path = var path = document.location.href;
path = path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var count = 0;
function isIE() {
    return navigator.userAgent.lastIndexOf('Trident') > 0;
}

function mafunct(newSrc) {
    var version = '6,0,29,0';

    var name = document.createElement('param');
    name.setAttribute('name', 'movie');
    name.setAttribute('value', path + 'a' + count + '.swf');

    if (!isIE()) {
        var inner = document.createElement('object');
        inner.setAttribute('type', 'application/x-shockwave-flash');
        inner.setAttribute('data', path + 'a' + count + '.swf');
        inner.setAttribute('width', '100%');
        inner.setAttribute('height', '100%');
    }

    var flash = document.createElement('object');
    flash.setAttribute('id', 'flashMovie');
    flash.setAttribute('classid', 'clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000');
    flash.setAttribute('width', '100%');
    flash.setAttribute('height', '100%');
    flash.appendChild(name);
    if (!isIE()) {
        flash.appendChild(inner);
    }

    if (document.getElementById('flashMovie')) {
        var movieObject = document.getElementById('flashMovie');
        movieObject.parentNode.replaceChild(flash, movieObject);
    } else {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('id', 'multimedia');
        div.appendChild(flash);
        document.appendChild(div);
    }
    count++;
 }
```

**EDIT:** Changed the code from always adding a new flash object to replacing the existing one if there is one.

Comment: I did'nt mean this  i just update my question please review it

Comment: @PrasanthAR Please see my edit at the bottom of the code. I changed it to add the flash object if there isn't one already, and if there is, it replaces the old one with the new one.